# Replacing a 38c tire with 30c

Tags: tire, wheels, commuter, bike-fit

I recently bought an Azor Opa style bike with 28x 1 1/2" (700 x 38c) tires that I want to switch out with something slimmer.  Would going down to 30c present a problem for my wheel perhaps?

Comment: Depends on the rim.  If the rim is relatively wide compared to the tire then you could have problems, but this is unlikely.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It will depend on the rim width, according to [Schwalbe's table of tire size to rim widths](http://www.schwalbetires.com/tech_info/tire_dimensions#rim) you'd be fine with a 17 or 19 mm rim and you'd be pushing it if you have a 21 mm rim.

Comment: Great chart.  I was looking around for something like this.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The bike would sit about 4 mm lower is the main thing (and technically, the gearing will change slightly).

You can mount the tire on there and it will work, but it may not be optimal depending on your [rim width](http://www.sheldonbrown.com/tire-sizing.html#width); if the rim is too wide for the tire, you may get more flats or rim damage when you hit a road hazard.

As for why you want to switch to something slimmer, if its for rolling resistance, you should read [this](http://www.sheldonbrown.com/brandt/rolling-resistance.html) and [this](http://www.schwalbetires.com/tech_info/rolling_resistance).

Comment: Thanks for the reply.  So is the thrust of that linked article that rolling resistance has more to do with the treading styles of wider and narrower tires?  I mainly want a thinner tire because they tend to accommodate higher PSI (for less rolling resistance and quicker response) and also because the brand of no-flat commuter tire I prefer (Specialized) seems to have their newest, best tire in the thinner size.  Thanks again for the advice.

Comment: For road, you want no tread ideally. The rolling resistance is a function of tread, type of material and tire construction. I've added a link to Schwalbe's page which is more clear on the details.